# Any performance issues using Google Web Fonts for mobile-only website?

Tags: mobile-safari, google-webfonts

I want to use css3 & google web fonts for the navigation (instead of graphics, for performance reasons).

Does anyone have experience with this? Are there drawbacks/limitations to using Google Web Fonts for a mobile client? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **What about performance? Will web fonts slow down my page?**
>
> If a page
>   uses web fonts, then the font files have to be downloaded to the site
>   visitor's computer before they can be displayed initially. The font
>   files are served compressed for a faster download. After that initial
>   download, they will be cached in the browser. As the Google Web Fonts
>   API becomes widely used, your visitors will be likely to already have
>   the font you're using in their browser cache when they visit your
>   page.
>
> In general, however, you should keep an eye on the size of the font
>   files you are serving. Also be aware that using web fonts may result
>   in the browser making more HTTP requests than would otherwise be
>   necessary.
>
> Compared to using images to display a lot of text on a page, web fonts
>   are likely to enhance the performance (and maintainability, and
>   accessibility) of your page. In other situations, however, they might
>   add to the overall weight of your page.

Quoted from https://developers.google.com/webfonts/faq#Performance

Comment: Thank you-- suppose I should have looked there first.

Answer (score 0):

As a personal experience, don't use web font on the main content text.

I used a web font which is very small (292 byte), and is hosted by Google CDN. The font is applied on a body level to all of the text.

When I actually uses a mobile phone to view the page, I see styled page with no text, and then have to wait for another second before the text appears. This can result in a perceived slowness.

The bottom line is: test and feel the app using a real phone. It is probably better not to apply web font to the main content.